# What is the difference between finally and finalize in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `RxJS` and I can see there are 2 function in `RxJS 5.5.2` available. Is the `.finally` will be removed and it will be placed in side `pipe()` from `RxJS 6.0.0` on wards is the reason or there are any other changes?

Are they both same and now final call is inside `pipe()`?

Or they have any notable difference?

#### finalize

```
method()
   .pipe(
     finalize(() => {
      // do some operation
     })
   )
```

#### finally

```
method()
  .finally(() => {
    // do your operation
  })
```

Comment: I think finally will be removed from `rxjs 6` on wards is the only change. Not sure if anything else is there

Answer (score 15):

Both are same functionality wise both does same operation of calling once observable is completed but difference is which version of rxjs you are using

Before v5.5 it is been called as finally

From v5.5 it is renamed to finalize(due to keyword restriction), because of the introduction to pipeable Operators which helps better tree shaking. For more info please check this [link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Answer (score 4):

They're very similar, but there is one notable difference that I can think of. `finalize` (by virtue of being an operator) doesn't have to be at the end of the `pipe`. This may seem insignificant, but depending on what operators are *behind* it in the chain there could be differences.

Consider for example a chain from a `fetch` that uses `shareReplay` to be shared between multiple components without retriggering an HTTP call. If you place `finalize` before `shareReplay` it will only be called once (because the `fetch` will only complete once), but if you place it *after* `shareReplay`, it will be called once per subscriber as `shareReplay` will create an Observable with its own finalize for each subscriber.